# Split the csv in to multiple csv based on matching word

Tags: shell, awk

I have a following csv

```
TEST,FILENAME1,COL3,COL4
AAAA,BBBBBBBB,CCCC,DDDD
DBDB,HHHDHHHD,UJUJ,UUUU
TEST,FILENAME2,COLX,COLY
1111,222222,2233,3333
33434,45566,6777,77777
jlkwj,reopwr,rewok,ewopk
```

I want to split the above file in 2 files. During parsing if I get a keyword called TEST i want to create a new file all the succeeding content should be going to a new file and the column next to TEST keyword should be filename

So the above example the files should be split as

FILENAME1.csv

```
TEST,FILENAME1,COL3,COL4
AAAA,BBBBBBBB,CCCC,DDDD
DBDB,HHHDHHHD,UJUJ,UUUU
```

FILENAME2.csv

```
TEST,FILENAME2,COLX,COLY
1111,222222,2233,3333
33434,45566,6777,77777
jlkwj,reopwr,rewok,ewopk
```

Is there an awk command which can do this for me? I have lot of csvs which have this content and I want to split each of them again in smaller chunks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F, '$1=="TEST"{close(out); out=$2".csv"} {print > out}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this:

```
awk -F, '{ if($1 == "TEST") file=$2} {print >> file".csv"}' example.txt
```

example.txt

```
TEST,FILENAME1,COL3,COL4
AAAA,BBBBBBBB,CCCC,DDDD
DBDB,HHHDHHHD,UJUJ,UUUU
TEST,FILENAME2,COLX,COLY
1111,222222,2233,3333
33434,45566,6777,77777
```

cat FILENAME1.csv

```
TEST,FILENAME1,COL3,COL4
AAAA,BBBBBBBB,CCCC,DDDD
DBDB,HHHDHHHD,UJUJ,UUUU
```

cat FILENAME2.csv

```
TEST,FILENAME2,COLX,COLY
1111,222222,2233,3333
33434,45566,6777,77777
jlkwj,reopwr,rewok,ewopk
```

If "TEST" can appear in any column, and not strictly in 1st column, then use this:

```
awk -F, '/TEST/ {file=$2} {print >> file".txt"}' example.txt
```

Comment: 1) You're confusing shells `>>` semantics with awks. In awk you should only use `>` in this context, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html. 2) An unparenthesized expression on the right side of output redirection is undefined behavior per POSIX so `print > file".txt"` will produce a syntax error in some awks, use `print > (file".txt")` instead. 3) If you don't close each output file when you move on to the next one you'll get a "too many open files" error once you reach about your 15th output file unless youre using GNU awk which handles the open files for you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. Please excuse my mistakes as I am still learning.

Comment: You're welcome. No problem and hopefully you'll continue to take any comments I leave on your answers in a positive way as I am just trying to help you and anyone else reading this learn, especially these kind of non-obvious gotchas!

Comment: Believe me, I am learning a lot from you. Yeah, it definitely helps many beginners like me. I am taking them all positively as I want to learn and improve. It would be my loss if I take it otherwise.

Comment: I tried this `awk -F, '{ if($1 == "TEST") file=$2} {print > file".csv"}' example.csv` and `awk -F, '{ if($1 == "TEST") file=$2} {print >> file".csv"}' example.csv` but didnt work `awk: syntax error at source line 1 context is { if($1 == "TEST") file=$2} {print >> >>> file".csv" <<< awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Comment: As @Ed Morton has pointed out, this can throw an error in certain AWKs. Try his answer. It worked fine in GNU awk.

Comment: Yeah that's due to item 2 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768706/split-the-csv-in-to-multiple-csv-based-on-matching-word/55769713?noredirect=1#comment98213213_55769713

Comment: @Ed Morton What is the correct way to do Item3 in your comment? (closing of file)

Comment: Thank you Ed Morton, acs005 both solutions worked. 2nd I had to update as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with csplit :

```
deb='FILENAME'
fin=".csv"
csplit -s -f "$deb" -b %1d"$fin" infile  1 %^TEST% /^TEST/
rm "${deb}0${fin}"
```